# Optional argument for which None is a valid value

Tags: python

I have the following function:

```
def item_by_index(iterable, index, default=Ellipsis):
    """Return the item of <iterable> with the given index.

    Can be used even if <iterable> is not indexable.

    If <default> is given, it is returned if the iterator is exhausted before
    the given index is reached."""

    iterable_slice = itertools.islice(iterable, index, None)
    if default is Ellipsis:
        return next(iterable_slice)
    return next(iterable_slice, default)
```

It should (and does) throw an exception if the `default` is not given and the iterator is exhausted too soon.  This is very similar to what the built-in function [`next`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next) does.

Usually, one would probably use `None` as default value to make an argument optional. In this case, however, `None` is a valid value for `default` and should be treated differently from no argument.  This is why I used `Ellipsis` as a default value.  It sort of feels like an abuse of the `Ellipsis` object, though.

Is there a better way of doing this or is `Ellipsis` a good tool for the job?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would argue the best option is to make an explicit sentinel value for this task. The best option in a case like this is a simple `object()` - it will only compare equal to itself (aka, `x == y` only when `x is y`).

```
NO_DEFAULT = object()

def item_by_index(iterable, index, default=NO_DEFAULT):
    ...
```

This has some semantic meaning, and means there is no potential overlap between a value a user wants to give and the default (I imagine it's highly unlikely they'd want to use Ellipses, but it's better to make as few assumptions as possible about use cases when writing functions). I'd recommend documenting it as such as well, as it allows the user to give a default/not using a variable, rather than having to change the call.

```
try:
    default = get_some_value()
except SomeException:
    default = yourmodule.NO_DEFAULT

item_by_index(some_iterable, index, default)
```

As opposed to having to do:

```
try:
    default = get_some_value()
except SomeException:
    item_by_index(some_iterable, index)
else:
    item_by_index(some_iterable, index, default)
```

The only downside it's not particularly clear what it is if you are looking at the object itself. You could create a custom class with a suitable `__repr__()`/`__str__()` and use an instance of it here.

As of Python 3 [enums have been added](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0435/) - the default type of enum only compares equal on identity, so a simple one with only the one value would also be appropriate (and is essentially just an easy way to do the above):

```
from enum import Enum
class Default(Enum):
    no_default = 0
```

Thanks to metaclass magic, `Default.no_default` is now an instance of a `Default`, which will only compare equal with itself (not `0`, by default, enums are pure).